# How to get libVLC to play segmented packets from a stream?

Tags: streaming, libvlc

I am curious as to how to use libVLC to play segments of a clip downloaded over the network. We are developing sort of a P2P program where packets can have several paths to get to the destination. Once it gets there I need to know how to play it. My idea is that it will be placed in a buffer and the player will play the packets in a FIFO manner.

The code I have is a modified version of [this tutorial](http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial). I know that it can directly receive streams and pretty much play whatever file we give it. However, I don't know how to do it so that I can place a segment of a file (obtained from the packets) into the buffer and let it play.

A lot of my search results in seeing libvlc_video_set_callbacks() but I fail to see how that helps. If it matters, we are only considering MP4 files for now and will expand later.

Comment: There has been some progress with this at the VideoLan Forums. [Link](http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=106510&p=360679#p360679)